# Microsoft Answers Engine

Tags: codeplex

Does anyone know what software microsoft is using to run their Microsoft Answers site. Is it a proprietary software or are they using a third party solution. Is it available on Codeplex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a custom, propietary, inhouse application. It's not available on Codeplex. [citation needed]

[This is all I could](http://forums.searchenginewatch.com/showthread.php?t=1375) [find on the matter](http://www.resourceshelf.com/2004/08/30/answer-engine-research-at-microsoft/).